# MS Graph API - getPstnCalls from C#

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I am having trouble figuring out how to call getPstnCalls from MS Graph in C#.  I am currently using the latest version of Graph, `Microsoft Graph 4.51.0`.  According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-getpstncalls) the way to call getPstnCalls and the way to call get callRecord is the same from C#.

```
var callRecord = await graphClient.Communications.CallRecords["{callRecords.callRecord-id}"]
    .Request().GetAsync();
```

It looks like there are several people asking for the documentation to be updated; some dating back to 2020 when getPstnCalls was still in beta.

I was expecting it to be something like:

```
var pstnCallLogRows = await graphClient.Communications.CallRecords.GetPstnCalls
    .Request().GetAsync();
```

Note that based on  I am expecting a completely different data type than what the documentation. (`List<pstnCallLogRow>` instead of `callRecord`)

Does anyone know how to actually make this call from C#?

Comment: When i try the endpoint in the graph explorer it creates `var callRecord = await graphClient.Communications.CallRecords["getPstnCalls"].Request().GetAsync();`

Comment: @Ralf, Unless I am missing something, that would still result in a return type of a single `CallRecord` object, not the expected `List<PstnCallLogRow>` [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/callrecords-pstncalllogrow).

That said, I had still tried that previously, hoping to get something back and I recall getting an error.  '...CallRecords["{callRecords.callRecord-id}"]' is expecting to have a valid ID.

Comment: could you pls try `await graphClient.Communications.CallRecords.Request().GetAsync();` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SDK 4.51 doesn't have support for `getPstnCalls` but there is a model `PstnCallLogRow` for `pstnCallLogRow` resource type.

You can at least try to create a http request and deserialize the response object.

```
var requestUrl = client
     .Communications
     .CallRecords
     .AppendSegmentToRequestUrl("getPstnCalls(fromDateTime=2023-01-18T06:00:00Z,toDateTime=2023-01-24T07:00:00Z)");

// create GET request message
var hrm = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUrl);

// authenticate request message
await client.AuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(hrm);

// send the request
var response = await client.HttpProvider.SendAsync(hrm);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    // read response json string - it should be a collection of pstnCallLogRow
    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    // deserialize to a collection of PstnCallLogRow
    var logRows = client.HttpProvider.Serializer.DeserializeObject<List<PstnCallLogRow>>(responseString);
}
else
{
    throw new ServiceException(
                    new Error
                    {
                        Code = response.StatusCode.ToString(),
                        Message = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This was a great solution. I did have to make one change to get the result to parse.  
```
var valueString = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(responseString)["value"].ToString();
var logRows = client.HttpProvider.Serializer.DeserializeObject<List<PstnCallLogRow>>(valueString);
```
There may be something besides Newtonsoft that can be used to parse the "value" out of the JSON, but I used it because I was already familiar with it and it was already installed in the project.

Comment: @DavidWatkins, can you please share the full code of the function, for me, AppendSegmentToRequestUrl throws error that CallRequestBuilder doesn't contain definition of AppendSegmentToRequestUrl. Also, what is the "client" object and how did you get it initiated?

Comment: @TechTurtle If you are using SDK v5, there can be breaking changes.